# filtros de busqueda php

Tags: php, mysqli, formularios, filtro

Tengo un filtro de busquedas hecho por php pero el caso es que solo me hace la busqueda sobre el primer filtro:

```
if (isset($_POST['buscador'])) {

    $filtros = []; //array de filtros que serán usados

//tipo de inmueble
        $tipo_inmueble = $_POST['tipo-inmueble'];

        if ($tipo_inmueble===0) {
        }else{
            array_push($filtros, $tipo_inmueble);
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM publicaciones where inmueble = '$filtros[0]'";
        }

//tipo de operacion
        $tipo_operacion = $_POST['tipo-operacion'];

        if ($tipo_operacion===0) {
        }else{
            array_push($filtros, $tipo_operacion);
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM publicaciones where inmueble = '$filtros[0]' and operacion = '$filtros[1]'";
        }


        // define how many results you want per page
        $results_per_page = 5;

        // find out the number of results stored in database

        $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
        $number_of_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if ($number_of_results==0) {
            echo "<p class='fallo-busqueda'>No se han encontrado coincidencias.</p>";
        }else{
```

ahi sigue mostrando los resultados....

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el caso es que si hago una busqueda me funciona correctamente, pero al querer realizar otra, el segundo valor siempre me le toma como 0, por lo que me da error siempre. Espero haberme explicado bien y que me podais ayudar, simplemente quiero poder hacer la busqueda sobre estos dos filtros

```
<form class="upload-form" action="index.php?option=busqueda" method="post">
    <select name="tipo-inmueble" id="tipo-inmueble">
        <option value="0">Elige tipo de inmueble...</option>
        <?php
        include_once('../../config/dbh.inc.php');

            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM tipos_inmueble';
            $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo '<option value='.$row['inmueble'].'>'.$row['inmueble'].'</option>';
        }
        ?>
    </select>

    <select name="tipo-operacion" id="tipo-operacion">
        <option value="0">Elige una operacion...</option>
        <?php
        include_once('../../config/dbh.inc.php');

            $sql_operacion = 'SELECT * FROM tipos_operacion';
            $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql_operacion);

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo '<option value='.$row['operacion'].'>'.$row['operacion'].'</option>';
        }
        ?>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" name="buscador" value="Buscar">
    </form>
```

Comment: Por que creas un array de filtros si solo puede seleccionar dos opciones?  o es un select multiple?

Comment: esa es una forma en la que tenia pensado hacerlo, son dos select como puedes comprobar